# How do I get the jSON key only on angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, multidimensional-array

My JSON looks like this:

```
{Sean/Projet: 6, EC2: 1},{EC3:5,Weekend:5}
```

How do I dynamically access only the key, for example: "Sean/Projet" or "EC2".

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't look like `[{Sean/Projet: 6, EC2: 1},{EC3:5,Weekend:5}]`?

Comment: it looks like this    {Sean/Projet: 6, EC2: 1} 
I think it is an object

Comment: That is a json object. And so is `{EC3:5,Weekend:5}`. The problem is the comma separating them, which implies an array.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the comma was introduced by me, I wanted to give 2 different examples not an array

Comment: Glad we cleared that up!

Answer (score 1):

You can find that out by sorting the object by values.

var sortedKeys = keys.sort((a,b)=>{return b-a})

Answer (score 0):

Found out a solution:

```
var keys = Object.keys(myJson);
console.log(keys[0]);
```

But how do I find out which key has the greater number?

Comment: You should ask a separate question for that